# List of figures by chapter in classic thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, classicthesis

I'm writing my thesis with classic thesis. It is possible to include the title of the chapter, but only when figure are present therein to the lof?

The use of listof =  chapterentry in the option to KOMA also include chapters without figures, and I would avoid these.

Thank you!!

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, titlepage, fleqn, headinclude, footinclude, BCOR5mm, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty, 
listof = withchapterentry]{scrbook}
%classic thesis template
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, eulermath, pdfspacing, listings, floatperchapter,parts]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the picture introduction and chapter one are also listed but contain no figures. I would avoid listing chapter without figures.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a minimal compilable document? It will save us a lot of time and avoids wrong guesses on our side. Thank you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi You have perfectly reason. I added it. Thank you

Comment: One way would be to remove the listof=chapterentry and write the corresponding records to the lof ONLY for the chapters with figures.  Another would be to modify the \listoffigures command to ignore a \contentsline{chapterenty}... if it is followed by another.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you this is a possible solution, and a good starting point for further tuning!

Comment: @JohnKormylo I can't believe I didn't thought at it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: tof]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, titlepage, fleqn, headinclude, footinclude, BCOR5mm, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=emptyast]{scrbook}
%classic thesis template
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, eulermath, pdfspacing, listings, floatperchapter,parts]{classicthesis}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterwithfigures}{\addxcontentsline{lof}{chapteratlist}[{\thechapter}]{\scr@ds@tocentry}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Introduction with no Figures}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Figures}
\chapterwithfigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter with no Figures}

\chapter{Another Test Chapter with Figures}
\chapterwithfigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```